# Problem with ADSafe and JSLint

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jslint

I am using the JSLint plugin for Eclipse from Rockstarapps and JSLint multi 1.1 (Yahoo Widgets)

On both I keep getting ADSafe warnigns, no matter if I check or uncheck the ADSafe checkbox in the JSLint settings.

I am not using and I don't need any ADSafe functionality, how to get rid of the JSLint warnings in JSLint multi and Eclipse?

*Edit*: I was using the Yahoo JSLint Multi Widget on Windows V 1.1

http://badge.ydp.clientapps.yahoo.com/badge/widgets/manual_download2?scen=u&wid=w6586

Answer (score 0):

I installed the JSLint plugin for Eclipse under Ubuntu 9.10 karmic, Eclipse 3.5 Galileo and had no problem turning on/off the adsafe warnings. Please give more data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I could not reproduce the behaviour now. But before it happened on 2 different machines. I need more time. It happens after cheking many files and doing changes, but I want to find out a way so others can reproduce it. I do not develop on this project at this time but when it continues I will provide more information as soon as I can trap the behaviour. Please note that I am the OP, SO does not display my name in comments correctly for some reason. - karlthorwald - aka